# How to create a deep copy of a generic array of primitive data types?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, primitive-types

I am trying to create a deep copy of a two-dimensional array of types int, double, boolean.

This question [Write a generic method to copy an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716135/write-a-generic-method-to-copy-an-array) helped me quite a bit (see below). But the problem is that actually in my code it would be a lot better to be able to simply deepCopy an array of primitive types.

```
private <T> T[][] arrayCopy(T[][] original) {
    Class<?> arrayType = original.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType();

    int[] dims = {original.length, original[0].length};
    T[][] copy = (T[][]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(arrayType, dims);

    for(int i = 0; i<dims[0]; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<dims[1], j++){
            copy[i][j] = original[i][j];
        }
    }
    return copy; 
}
```

I have very limited knowledge about Java generics and I am unsure if what I wish is possible. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Since Java 5, all premitive data type has corresponding object type. it is totally fine for you to go with the way you shows. What's your problem?

Comment: If you just want a deep copy, calling clone() is sufficient on 2d arrays of ints, doubles etc.

Comment: You can't use generics with primitive types. The `T` (or whatever) generic type variable is only compatible with Object types (classes, interfaces, enums).

Comment: @SatyendraKumar How so? That's not a deep copy. Each element in the array points to the same element as the old array. Change one of the ints in one, and it changes in the other.

Comment: Also note that your method is incorrect. It assumes the array is rectangular (that all elements have the same size). That's not generally correct for Java arrays. You can have a `T[][]` with three elements in the first row, none in the second row, and 600 in the third row, etc.

Comment: @QingfeiYuan when I use an int[][] as argument, the program does not compile, saying "method... cannot be applied to given types, required T[][], given int[][]". So I guess RealSkeptic is right, that generics cannot be used with primitive types...

Answer (score 0):

Generics doesn't work for primitive types. Arrays of primitives are reference types and you could use generics to match the input and output types, but you can't apply a bound to check that it's an array type because the only supertype of primitive array types is `Object`. To have the same code work on all array types, you would have to use the special methods in `java.lang.reflect.Array` to get and set array elements, get length, etc.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

private <T> T[] arrayCopy2d(T[] original) {
    Class<?> arrayType = original.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType();

    int[] dims = {original.length, Array.getLength(original[0])};
    T[] copy = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arrayType, dims);

    for(int i = 0; i<dims[0]; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<dims[1], j++){
            Array.set(copy[i], j, Array.get(original[i], j));
        }
    }
    return copy; 
}
```